# Why my recursive function doesn't return the right value?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I'm implementing a binary search and the code is below, however, it doesn't print out the right answer buy it prints out correct answer inside the function body, so it makes me really confused.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int research(int a[], int target, int lowIndex, int highIndex)
{
    int finalIndex;
    cout << lowIndex << " " << highIndex << endl;
    int midIndex = (lowIndex + highIndex) / 2;
    if (a[midIndex] == target)
    {
        finalIndex = midIndex;
        cout << "The final index is: " << finalIndex << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (a[midIndex] < target)
        {
            research(a, target, midIndex + 1, highIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            research(a, target, lowIndex, midIndex - 1);
        }
    }
    return finalIndex;
}

int main()
{
    int* array = new int[1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        array[i] = i + 1;
    }
    cout << research(array, 234, 0, 999) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The line:

```
cout << "The final index is: " << finalIndex << endl;
```

prints out the right final index but the line

```
cout << research(array, 234, 0, 999) << endl;
```

doesn't, instead it prints out random number. Anyone know what is going wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: Missing `return` statements in your `if` and `else` blocks.

Comment: You are in the most serious need of revising basic programming concepts. In particular, programming is not magic, the compiler is not a mind reader, and calling a function doesn't automatically insert `return` statements (C++ is not an expression language). Maybe you meant to assign the return value of the recursive calls to `finalIndex`; better yet, just return them.

Answer (score 1):

The only time you actually set `finalIndex` to anything is when `a[midIndex] == target`, so when you recurse you're returning the value of an uninitialised variable.

(The `finalIndex` variable isn't shared between function invocations - each invocation uses its own variable.)

You need to use the return value from the recursive calls:

```
    if (a[midIndex] < target)
    {
        finalIndex = research(a, target, midIndex + 1, highIndex);
    }
    else
    {
        finalIndex = research(a, target, lowIndex, midIndex - 1);
    }
```

Comment: Oh! I totally forgot about that! Thank you so much!